# How to create repeted seq in informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to generate repeated seq using Informatica mapping.

Src file

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

Trg file

```
A 1
B 1
C 2
D 2
E 3
F 3
G 4 
H 4
I 5 
J 5
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try Sequence Generator Transformation ? https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-1/_transformation-guide_powercenter_10-1_ditamap/sequence_generator_transformation/sequence_generator_transformation_overview.html

Comment: Yes, I tried, but unable to generate repeated seq, I can generate cycle using seq trans like 1 2 1 2 1 2  but I want 1 1 2 2 3 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Sequence Generator, and then an Expression that divides the value of NEXTVAL by 2:

```
OUT: ROUND(NEXTVAL / 2)
```

In the Sequence Generator you could set "Start Value" to 1 and check "Reset" so that the mapping always starts with 1 1 2 2 3 3 if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using variable ports in an Expression transformation, as long as your input rows are sorted in the correct order. e.g. (pseudocode)

```
v_RowCount = v_RowCount + 1

v_Seq = if v_RowCount Mod 2 = 0 then (v_Seq + 1) else v_Seq

(Output port) out_Seq = v_Seq
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives output starting with 0 but if you interchange first 2 lines, it works perfect (1,1,2,2,3,3....).

```
v_Seq = iff(v_RowCount % 2 = 0 ,(v_Seq + 1) , v_Seq)
v_RowCount = v_RowCount + 1
(Output port) out_Seq = v_Seq
```